# Error launching ddms.bat: "Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "adb": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: adb, 2.1-eclair, usb-debugging, screenshots

I've been following [these very detailed instructions to take a screenshot on my Motorola Flipside](http://www.knowyourcell.com/motorola/motorola-flipside/flipside-guides/624449/how_to_take_screenshots_on_the_motorola_flipside.html). When I get to the step #10 where I launch `ddms.bat` I get this error and my phone doesn't show up:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools>ddms.bat
>      12:09:01 E/adb: Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "adb": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

(and here I thought the difficulties of taking screenshots on Android were exaggerated)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding `adb`'s folder (`platform-tools`) to your PATH. The `adb` executable used to be in the `tools` folder on versions of the SDK up to v8 IIRC, but it was moved in v9, so ddms.bat is probably looking for it in the wrong spot.

See also [this thread on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378438/ddms-throwing-adb-error-since-sdk-api-9-upgrade) (accepted answer there courtesy one of our mods here) to see if this is in fact the issue.

**Edit**: If you need it, [here's a decent guide](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) for changing your PATH environment variable. It's written for XP but I don't think the process is much different (if at all) for Vista/7. The basic premise is at least the same.

**Another edit**: It looks like it's the same process according to [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20210213041100/http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx) for Win7.

Comment: copying the `adb.exe` just crashed it on launch: Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: adb.exe
  Application Version: 0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 4ced84a4
  Fault Module Name: AdbWinApi.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.0.6002.18005
  Fault Module Timestamp: 49e03824
  Exception Code: c0000135
  Exception Offset: 0006f04e
  OS Version: 6.0.6002.2.2.0.256.6
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 9d13
  Additional Information 2: 1abee00edb3fc1158f9ad6f44f0f6be8
  Additional Information 3: 9d13
  Additional Information 4: 1abee00edb3fc1158f9ad6f44f0f6be8

Comment: @travis: Try adding it to your PATH, then. I'd never tried copying it, to be honest.

Comment: Yep was just about to post this :)  Gingerbread SDK broke things by moving the location of adb.exe

Comment: It didn't refresh the %Path% globally, so I just did it via the command line before launching the BAT file: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools>SET Path=%Path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools` then `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools>ddms.bat`

Comment: Adding the platform-tools path to my System Environment Variable PATH worked for me.  Thanks!